# ajax is loading data twice from database using laravel php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

hi i am trying to load data from database using ajax . but the data is loading twice on the html page.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $('button').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"{{route('zaeemajax')}}",
            method:"get",
            datatype:"json",
            success:function(response){
                 console.log(response);
                var tabledata="";
                $.each(response,function(key,value){
                 tabledata +="<tr>";
                 tabledata +="<td>"+value.name+"</td>";
                 tabledata +="<td>"+value.price+"</td>";
                 tabledata +="<td>"+value.category+"</td>";
                 tabledata +="</tr>";
                
                });
                  $('#show tbody').append(tabledata);
            }


        });

    });
</script>
```

in my controller i am return product data as json

```
public function showallpro()
    {
        $product=Product::all();
        return response()->json($product);

    }
```

there are only two fields right now in the products table but wheneever i try to fetch data from database it is showing the same data twice

here is the html code where i am trying to show the fecthed data from the data base

```
<table id="show" style="border: 1px solid black;">
    <tr>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Category</th>

    </tr>
    <tbody>

</tbody>
</table>

<button type="">Show Data</button>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you by any chance have two elements that match the selector `$('#show tbody')`?

Comment: Use `.html(tabledata)`  instead of `.append(tabledata)`

Comment: Used .html(tabledata) instead of .append(tabledata) the result remains teh same data is loading twice .

Comment: no i dont have two selector with the id of #show .

Comment: use `$('button').one("click",()=>{ //ajax code here });` or `$('button').once("click",()=>{ //ajax code here });`. But you shoud use a different selector like "button" elements can be more than one in the same page, use Id or class of button instead.

Comment: Verify what is being appended with `console.log(tabledata);`. That will tell you if it's the loop or if it's something else.

Comment: add `<thead></thead>` tags as well .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only problem i was having that data was loading twice so i made the following changes and it worked

i changed this

$('#show').append(tabledata);

instead of

$('#show tbody').append(tabledata);